# Come back to starting point in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a really really beginner in iOS programming. I'm trying to develop a countdown timer, which seems to be a good exercise.

I use a single view based application with a unique controller. On this controller, I've put a "Start" button (displayed when starting) and a "Stop" button (hidden when starting). When the user hits the "Start" button after having selected a countdown time, the "Start" button disappears and the "Stop" button appears. I would like to allow the user to come back to the starting point when hitting the "Stop" button.

I've read about the following solution :

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But this doesn't work for me because my app only has a single controller.

Has any of you an idea to solve my problem ? Must I create another controller ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

PS : Forgive my bad english, I'm French.

Comment: Are you just setting `startButton.hidden = YES`? If so, the solution should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Do you use storyboards / interface builder to create the view controller? Did you declare the buttons as outlets and properties? Can you maybe show some code?

Comment: It would actually be helpful if you post the code of the whole view controller (I assume it's not that much yet), so that we can help you spot the details :) PS. your english is completely ok, despite the fact that you're french ;)

Comment: Did you make any progress with your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an NSTimer somewhere doing the counting.  When the user hits the stop button, you can invalidate the timer by doing something like this.

```
[timer invalidate];
```

You can then change the button back to being the start button and reset any textfield text to the o.o second start time.

Answer (score -1):

just save any important changes before the user hits the "start" button, then restore it when he hits "stop".
Hope i got what you mean